# What happens if you need to be sent to a hospital in a country you don't have a visa for, e.g. on a cruise ship?

Tags: visas, health, cruising, emergencies

So I presume there's a requirement that you have a visa for each country you visit on a cruise ship, although I've never done one.

However, if you're passing a country that you're not actually stopping at, and a passenger gets ill (eg the recent norovirus outbreaks that one of my friends was part of on a Europe cruise) and needs to be airlifted to a hospital, how do they choose where to send them, and what if it's a country you don't have a visa for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would expect most countries to allow exceptions to their usual immigration procedures in cases of emergency (there may even be some pieces of international legislation about this). Japan does, in [Article 17 of its Immigration Control and Refugee Recognition Act](http://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/law/detail_main?re=02&vm=&id=1934#en_ch3sc4at4):

> In the case of disease or any other accident which urgently requires
>   the landing of a foreign national aboard a vessel or aircraft for the
>   purpose of medical treatment, an immigration inspector may grant
>   permission for emergency landing to the foreign national concerned
>   based on an application by the captain of the vessel or aircraft or
>   the carrier who operates the vessel or aircraft until the cause
>   thereof ceases to exist, subject to a medical examination by a
>   physician designated by the Minister of Health, Labour and Welfare or
>   the Minister of Justice.

(Note that in Japanese immigration parlance, *landing* means entering Japan by passing through immigration, etc.)